# Python. Как сделать задержку, не заморозив программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, таймер, sleep

При использовании time.sleep(x), вся программа останавливается. Я же делаю бота, в котором после каждого действия нужно ждать. Ты же не можешь работать весь день без остановки? Нет, не можешь. После каждой работы нужно будет отдохнуть 1 реальный час. Но time.sleep(x) останавливает ВСЮ программу, и после каждой работы никто не может пользоватся ботом. Как сделать задержку, без заморозки программы?

Comment: Запоминать время последнего запроса от каждого пользователя и проверять его, например.

Comment: Объясни понятнее. Если бот должен не работать, а его-то ждать, то какая разница, могут им пользоваться или нет, если пользоваться им все равно нельзя. Ведь нужно отдохнуть реальный час.

Comment: Надо же, первый раз вижу такую трогательную заботу о том, чтобы бот не переутомился...

Comment: @strawdog к сожалению, это не для бота :( Мой бот игровой, так сказать "симулятор жизни", и чтобы человек не злоупотреблял и не спамил командой чтобы получить много денег, надо сделать отдых

Comment: По идее у Вас для  каждой команды есть обработчик. В нем можно получить время запроса и при повторе команды вычитать его из текущего. Если итог меньше часа то программа должна дать отказ.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вы должны использовать asyncio.sleep(3600) в своём боте.
Тогда ваша задача будет асинхронной и остальные команды будут работать.

Comment: Это не является ответом на вопрос, не смотря на то, что вопрос так себе, на "двоечку". Но вы можете оформить ваш совет как комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо, но asyncio нужно подключать через импорт? Если да, то его можно установить через пип, или это встроенная библиотека?

Comment: @strawdog согласен с вами, тут логика будет сложнее, вам нужно будет хранить состояние каждого пользователя и отдельно для каждого message.user_id запоминать текущее состояние, обычным asyncio.sleep это не получится сделать. Просто я думал, что вы имеете в виду асинхронный таск, который каждый n количество времени, повторяет свои действия.

Answer (score -1):

Можете попробовать открыть функцию которой требуется отдых в многопотоке, в таком случае останавливаться будет только функция, а программа продолжит работу

```
from threading import Thread

a = Thread(target=ваша функция)
a.start()
```